# what is the best and fastest way to communicate between two applications?

Tags: java, inter-process-communicat

I made a java program just for fun this program allows you to control the seconds computer mouse using the first computer's mouse. so everytime the mouse moves some the x and the y of the cursor is sent client application. which then uses the robot class to move the mouse. right now I am using sockets to communicate and it is really slow what is a better way to do it any help would be apritited. if possible please provide some code 
thanks

Comment: Well, where does the slowness come from? Benchmark!

Comment: ... tagged jsp? this *other* application, is it web based?

Comment: oops sorry didn't ment jsp mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If both applications *live* in different virtual machines, then communication via sockets is a very good approach.

If it is too slow, you may consider

- using UDP protocol instead of TCP/IP
- look at you server/client code, performance may be killed there.

---

Considering you comment to this answer:

As you send *bytes* over sockets, performance will be increased if you encode the mouse positions to `byte` values rather then to `String`:

```
int x = getX();
int y = getY();
// let's assume we have a 16Bit / 2Byte range for both values (practica)
byte[] message = new byte[4];
message[0] = (byte) (x >> 8) & 0xff;
message[1] = (byte) x & 0xff;
message[2] = (byte) (y >> 8) & 0xff;
message[3] = (byte) y & 0xff;
sendViaSocket(message);
```

(It starts and ends with some magic, the point is the encoding)

Comment: Show us some code from your sending/receiving methods - there may be *room for improvement*

Comment: I am not sure if this even a valid question but still I will ask. what I am pretty much doing is sending the x and y string to client which then parses the string and moves the mouse to the given x and y is this a good aproach or is there a better one?

Answer (score 1):

I guess sockets was your best bet. You can try to research more info about JFS (Java Fast Sockets) which is a project from the University of A Coruña in Spain, but I'm not sure how far they went with it. More info [here](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/java-fast-sockets-enabling-high-speed-java-communications-on-high-performance-clusters/1327)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways for inter process communication between two machines - But I don't think any of them are going to be faster than raw sockets and will work for mouse events:

1. Use JMS queue
2. Use a DB
3. Use a WS